# Capistrano before hook for all tasks

Tags: capistrano

I want to run a function before any Capistrano v2.X task is invoked in the `deploy` namespace.

I have the following which works for a specific task, but how do I hook for all tasks in the namespace, not just a particular task?

```
before "deploy:justin" do
  puts "in before hook"
  my_funnction_here
end

namespace :deploy do
  task :justin do
    puts "in task justin"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some built in points in Capistrano's deployment flow that you can hook into.

For example you can do:

```
before 'deploy:starting', :some_task do
    # Your code here
end
```

See http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/flow/ for the list.

I think with that and a little reshuffling of your current code you can make it work. Hope that helps.